# How to use Mercurial to deploy Django applications?

Tags: python, django, mercurial, apache2, mod-python

I'm creating a server with Apache2 + mod_python + Django for development and would like to know how to use Mercurial to manage application development.

My idea is to make the folder where the Mercurial stores the project be the same folder to deploy Django.

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: Really, you shouldn't be using mod_python. To answer your question :use wsgi with code reloading and you'll be all set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought about this, good idea for development.
Use mercurial in common way. And of course you need deploy mercurial server before.
If you update your django project, it will be compiled on the fly.

My workflow:

1. Set up mercurial server or use bitbucket
2. Init repo locally
3. Push repo to central repo
4. On server pull repo in some target dir
5. Edit smth locally and push to central repo
6. Pull repo on server and everything is fine

Comment: Can you please point to some article that actually tackles this use case? You answer would be much more helpful and you'd get much more upvotes for it.